# How do I activate a Prison Architect steam code?

Tags: prison-architect

So I bought a special edition of Prison Architect, but I don't know how to activate the code. Do I have to enter the code somewhere in the game? or somewhere else? I have the 'Prison Architect Name in Game Edition Key'. Does the key not work after a certain date?

Comment: Did you confirm the key in one of the formats the "Product Activation" window says it must be? Where did you buy the key from?

Comment: I bought the game that came with a key from steam. Yes I am pretty sure that the format is correct.

Comment: If you bought it from Steam, then you already have it activated on Steam and you just need to install the game.

Comment: I did install the game.

Comment: What are you trying to do, then? "Activate" is only for adding a new game to Steam that you got from elsewhere.

Comment: well what do I do with the key? I don't think it activated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the benefits that come with the "your name in the game" portion of your key, you need to follow the instructions in [this link](http://support.introversion.co.uk/customer/portal/articles/1007776-name-in-the-game).  Upshot is, you need to contact the developers and they will work your request.

Otherwise, your key is activated on Steam and has given you the game (and after a check of the product page, should have given you all of Introversion's other titles as well), and that should be all it does on Steam.